# Abrir uma blank page com uma imagem ao ser clicada vinda do Banco de Dados (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou conseguindo listar no HTML todas as imagens salvas no meu Banco de Dados, porém gostaria que ao clicar em alguma, abrisse uma blank page com a imagem, mas não sei o que colocar no href, pois os dados da imagem vem do Banco de Dados.

Código:

```
<span class="ml-2">
   <a href="O QUE COLOCO AQUI?" target="_blank">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="<?= 'data:' . $anexo['tipo'] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($anexo['arquivo']) ?>" alt="Photo" style="width: 80px; height: 80px !important;">
   </a>
</span>
```

Banco de Dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: se não tiver uma url para ponde postar, use `#`

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que abra a imagem em uma outra tela, coloque  o caminho para  a imagem.
Exemplo:

href="**pasta/imagem.jpg**" target="_blank"

no seu caso, coloque o mesmo que está no src da imagem dentro do href:

```
<?= 'data:' . $anexo['tipo'] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($anexo['arquivo']) ?>
```

Comment: Já tentei, abre uma página sem nada.

Comment: Coloca o código que está utilizando no href.